# Problema ao verificar uma query no PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um `if` do qual deve verificar se o JOIN que possui uma linha com 3 colunas de registros com o objetivo de impedir que haja um novo cadastro do mesmo produto e fornecedor, só que não verifica.

Dei um `var_dump()` no `$linha_qnt` e retorna `int(0)`

O erro é a linha `$linha_qnt = $seleciona_qnt->columnCount();`

```
    $cd_fornecedor = intval($_POST['cd_fornecedor']);
    $cd_produto = intval($_POST['cd_produto']);

    $procurar_fornecedor = "SELECT nome FROM fornecedor WHERE cd_fornecedor = :cd_fornecedor LIMIT 1";
    $busca_fornercedor = $conexao->prepare($procurar_fornecedor);
    $busca_fornercedor->bindValue(':cd_fornecedor', $cd_fornecedor);
    $busca_fornercedor->execute();
    $linha1 = $busca_fornercedor->fetch();
    $nome_fornecedor = $linha1['nome'];

    $procurar_produto = "SELECT nome, codigo_barra FROM produto WHERE cd_produto = :cd_produto LIMIT 1";
    $busca_produto = $conexao->prepare($procurar_produto);
    $busca_produto->bindValue(':cd_produto', $cd_produto);
    $busca_produto->execute();
    $linha2 = $busca_produto->fetch();
    $nome_produto = $linha2['nome'];
    $codigo_produto = $linha2['codigo_barra'];

    $qnt_registro = "SELECT COUNT(fornecedor.nome) AS forn_nome, 
    COUNT(produto.nome) AS prod_nome, COUNT(produto.codigo_barra) AS prod_cod FROM compra_fornecedor
    INNER JOIN fornecedor ON (fornecedor.cd_fornecedor = compra_fornecedor.cd_fornecedor)
    INNER JOIN produto ON (produto.cd_produto = compra_fornecedor.cd_produto)
    WHERE fornecedor.nome = {$nome_fornecedor} AND produto.nome = {$nome_produto} 
    AND produto.codigo_barra = {$codigo_produto} ";
    $seleciona_qnt = $conexao->prepare($qnt_registro);
    $seleciona_qnt->execute();
    $linha_qnt = $seleciona_qnt->columnCount(); // ERRO

    if ($linha_qnt != 0) {
        echo "O fornecedor {$nome_fornecedor} já possui uma compra 
        cadastrada de {$nome_produto} com código de barra {$codigo_produto}.";
        echo '<p><a href="../form_crud/form_insert_compra.php" title="Refazer operação"><button>Refazer operação</button></a></p>';
        die;
    }
```

Comment: ```qtn_registro``` retorna uma query com 3 colunas: ```forn_nome, prod_nome, prod_cod```. Cada uma deles possui um ```count()```

Comment: Qual é resultado de [`PDO::errorInfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.errorinfo.php) antes e depois de `$linha_qnt = $seleciona_qnt->columnCount();`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode retornar os resultados com o `fetchObject()` ou `fetchAll()` e validar assim:

```
$linha_qnt = $seleciona_qnt->fetchObject();
if ($linha_qnt->forn_nome != 0) {
    echo "O fornecedor {$nome_fornecedor} já possui uma compra cadastrada de {$nome_produto} com código de barra {$codigo_produto}.";
    echo '<p><a href="../form_crud/form_insert_compra.php" title="Refazer operação"><button>Refazer operação</button></a></p>';
    die;
}
```

Apenas verifique se tem necessidate de retornar essas três colunas com contador (`forn_nome`, `prod_nome`, `prod_cod`). O `columnCount()` retorna o número de colunas do resultado, acho que não é o que precisa.